# How to make a DIV match floating child's height (floating columns) and yet allow child elements to protrude on the sides

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm designing a layout with 3 columns, based on a div containing 3 floating divs.

The problem is the container div doesn't match the columns' height as I intend it to. It acts as if it had no content at all, and therefore the 3 columns protrude vertically.

To fix this I tried with overflow:hidden and it made the trick, but my design had a div that sticks out on the left that got messed up as this attribute won't let anything stick out.

Is there a better way to fix the height problem? Thanks.

Comment: Show us your HTML, show us your current CSS, show us a picture of what you want it to look like. Ideally, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) [live demo of your current code](http://jsfiddle.net/) so we can see what's going on, and more easily suggest, and demonstrate, changes. Basically: help us to help you. (To include further information in your question use the 'edit' link, below the tags; please don't try posting code in the comments.)

Answer (score 5):

you can usually make the container's height extend to the end of its children by throwing in a `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` right after all your children.. like this.

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="child0"></div>
    <div class="child1"></div>
    <div class="child2"></div>

    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure if that is considered a hack or not by the community. but I use it sometimes. also, I've seen people not use a div, but an `<hr>` and apply that style as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use a clearfix class - that should do the job:

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}
.clearfix {
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

Check http://jsfiddle.net/YyMjJ/1/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I've understood the question correctly, you could use a clearing div:

```
   <div id="dre">
        <div class="float" style="height:100px"></div>
        <div class="float" style="height:200px"></div>
        <div class="float" style="height:30px"></div>
        <div id="clear"></div>
    </div>
```

See it here - http://jsfiddle.net/C7FCC/